# Running SwiftUI app on macOS, but the platform is recognized as iOS. Why?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Running the app on macOS, but the app does not recognize the platform as macOS:

```
#if os(iOS)
        NavigationView {
            let _ = print("platform is iOS")
            ProfileView()
        }
            #else
        NavigationView {
            let _ = print("platform is NOT iOS")
            ProfileView()
        }
// platform is iOS
```

Have I missed some crucial steps?

Comment: you probably have a macCatalyst app. They are considered as ios apps. You can also check  using `#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem. The app running on macOS is a macCatalyst app, so you have to take that into consideration:

```
#if os(OSX)
        NavigationView {
            let _ = print("platform is macOS")
            ProfileView()
        }
        
 #elseif os(iOS)
    

    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        NavigationView {
            let _ = print("platform is macCatalyst")
            ProfileView()
        }
            #else
        NavigationView {
            let _ = print("platform is iOS")
            ProfileView()
        }
        #endif
        #endif
// platform is macCatalyst.
```